# USB flash drive suddenly stops working, file system cannot be determined

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a Corsair Voyager Slider 16GB USB drive (USB 3.0)

I was working using my USB yesterday and after a 30 minutes break I went back to continue and suddenly my USB stopped working completely, telling me that the device drivers failed to install and basically I literally cannot access it at all. I tried to scan it for bad sectors etc, using both CHKDSK function on cmd and also the window which pops up once you insert your USB drive in the port but it tells me that it cannot open volume for direct access. What's also strange is that suddenly my USB drive is FAT32, I'm not sure if this is how it always has been but what I am for sure, I've never had any problems with it until yesterday. I also cannot convert it to NTFS as it tells me it cannot determine the file system. When I check the properties it tells me that I have 0 bytes free memory and 0 bytes actual memory. Everything just went haywire.

I have a lot and a lot of data that I hadn't saved yet all day so I HAVE to find a way to recover this data. Is it a lost cause or is there anything which can be done to recover this dat

Comment: Things to try: (1) change USB port; (2) reboot and plug it in again; (3) plug into a different PC; (4) install file recovery software. If your drive has a write-protect switch, keep it on until you have finished recovering.

Comment: 1.) doesn't work, 2.) doesn't work, 3.) same story, 4.) It just doesn't recognize the USB, it only recognizes it as RAW. I'm using EaseUS for software...

Comment: Try Convar's [PC Inspector](http://www.pcinspector.de/default.htm?language=1) file recovery freeware: I have used it in the past and found it very good. It will not repair your drive, but will copy whatever files it can reconstruct from a sector-by-sector scan.